# Extensions method replaces the standard method in C#

Tags: c#, static, extension-methods

There are ways to use extension methods with signatures of standard methods as extension (without explicit appeal to static class)? For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Own";
    }
}

public static class ExtensionsMethods
{
    public static string ToString(this Foo foo)
    {
        return "Extensions";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();            
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString()); // "Own" will be printed
    }
}
```

Can I use Extensions-`ToString` version without explicit appeal to class `ExtensionsMethods`

Comment: No offence intended but you can answer this without asking. Check the Extension Method msdn documentation. It won't be called if there exists another method with same signature no matter what, till the time the existing method can be called. Extension Methods get the least priority on getting called.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. An extension method is not used if a method with the same signature is available:

> You can use extension methods to extend a class or interface, but not
>   to override them. An extension method with the same name and signature
>   as an interface or class method will never be called.

See [*Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)* with *Binding Extension Methods at Compile Time*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for details.

There might be inheritance or a [decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) as an alternative solution for you.